# Multiple Value Select with Inner Join 3 table

Tags: mysql

how to Get Value not multiple per Result

```
SELECT annual_leave.id_annual_leave, approve_cuti_tanggal.tanggal_request_izin, tbl_timesheet.shift FROM annual_leave 
INNER JOIN approve_cuti_tanggal ON approve_cuti_tanggal.id_annual = annual_leave.id_annual_leave 
INNER JOIN tbl_timesheet ON tbl_timesheet.id_annual = annual_leave.id_annual_leave
WHERE approve_cuti_tanggal.keterangan='APPROVAL HEAD NOC' AND annual_leave.status='APPROVAL'
```

[image]

From Table Approval_tanggal Only 2 Value
[image]

And tbl_timesheet too
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use

`select distinct * from <table_name>`

[You can refer to MySQL documentation.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/distinct-optimization.html)